# Only pull IP Address from a line of text

Tags: ruby

I've got a script that searches through a logfile for a specific trigger, and then pulls out the line when it's found.  For example, this is a line I'm looking for:

```
7/2/10 9:24:12 AM puppetmasterd[63092] Could not resolve 10.13.1.190: no name for 10.13.1.190
```

It saves this line into a variable "line", but I'd like to be able to extract only the IP Address.

Our IP Addresses all start with 10.13 - is there an easy way to search for that in this variable and then isolate ONLY the IP address into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matches = line.scan(/10\.13\.[12]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.[12]?[0-9]?[0-9]/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to read about [regular expressions on Ruby](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html).  Your specific problem is fairly easy, so it would be a good learning exercise. (Try the [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) if the first link is too advanced!)